# Django using a variable from urls passed to views to determine which form to show

Tags: django-forms, django-views, django-urls

I have 4 ModelForm forms which are very similar (ColorForm / MaterialForm ...). Im using this view:

```
def add_attr(request):
 ColorFormSet = formset_factory(ColorForm, extra=1)
 if request.method == "POST":
     user = request.user
     formset = ColorFormSet(request.POST)
     if formset.is_valid():
         for form in formset:
             new_form = form.save(commit=False)
             new_form.designer = user
             new_form.save()
     return HttpResponseRedirect('/problema_solucion/add/')
 else:
    cform = ColorForm(request.POST, instance=Color())
 return render(request, 'add_attribute.html', {'formset': ColorFormSet,})
```

my url

```
url(r'^designer/add_Color/$', views.add_attr),
```

I want to change it to

```
url(r'^designer/add_{var}/$', views.add_attr)
```

I think that in the views I need to add

```
def add_attr(request, var)
```

but Im not being able to switch from

```
ColorFormSet to (%sFormset %var)
```

I get a syntax error

Comment: Please paste error message with full traceback also proper indent your views.py

Comment: here it is, quite long tho: